# Use a regex to check cron entry '0 5 * * * /usr/bin/aide --check'

Tags: regex, rspec, serverspec, inspec

How do I check the cron entry `0 5 * * * /usr/bin/aide --check` with a regex? I would like to check this in Chef InSpec like

```
its('content') { should match /<the regular expression>/ }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe cron do
  it { expect(subject).to have_entry '0 5 * * * /usr/bin/aide --check' }
end
```

is the proper way to do this in Serverspec and will also solve your problem with formatting immediately.

If you really wanted to use a regexp (and your followup comment left as an answer implies you don't), then you could do:

```
its(:content) { is_expected.to match %r{0 5 \* \* \* /usr/bin/aide --check} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex could be `/0 5 * * * \/usr\/bin\/aide --check/`

Comment: And escape the asterisks?